# BIND DNS zone coalfired.net/IN: coalfired.net.coalfired.net/NS 'ns2.thirteen.pm.coalfired.net' has no address records (A or AAAA)

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, bind

Since I updated my BIND DNS server I seem to be having problems with it. For some reason, when I try to start the server I get errors such as this appear:

> zone coalfired.net/IN: coalfired.net.coalfired.net/NS
>   'ns2.thirteen.pm.coalfired.net' has no address records (A or AAAA)

For some reason, it seems to be naming my records as 'coalfired.net.coalfired.net/NS' - so the format domain.domain. I guess it should be reading 'coalfired.net/NS'.

This is happening for every domain on my server which is running CentOS 6.5 and Virtualmin. My config files are below.

Relevant section of /etc/named.conf:

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { localhost; };
    recursion yes;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

zone "coalfired.net" {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/coalfired.net.hosts";
    allow-transfer {
        127.0.0.1;
        localnets;
        };
    };
```

/var/named/coalfired.net.hosts:

```
$ttl 38400
@   IN  SOA ns1.thirteen.pm. root.ns1.thirteen.pm. (
            1397293687
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
@   IN  NS  ns1.thirteen.pm.
coalfired.net.  IN  A   5.9.35.30
www.coalfired.net.  IN  A   5.9.35.30
ftp.coalfired.net.  IN  A   5.9.35.30
m.coalfired.net.    IN  A   5.9.35.30
localhost.coalfired.net.    IN  A   127.0.0.1
webmail.coalfired.net.  IN  A   5.9.35.30
admin.coalfired.net.    IN  A   5.9.35.30
mail.coalfired.net. IN  A   5.9.35.30
coalfired.net.  IN  MX  5 mail.coalfired.net.
coalfired.net.  IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx a:coalfired.net ip4:5.9.35.30 ?all"
coalfired.net IN NS ns2.thirteen.pm
autoconfig.coalfired.net.   IN  A   5.9.35.30
```

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loks like you are missing the dot at the end of your NS record.
This

```
coalfired.net IN NS ns2.thirteen.pm
```

should be

```
coalfired.net. IN NS ns2.thirteen.pm.
```

[The DOT in a Zone File](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/apa/dot.html)

Comment: This is on the right track but I guess your example should say `coalfired.net. IN NS ns2.thirteen.pm.` or `@ IN NS ns2.thirteen.pm.`

Comment: Thanks both. Yes this was the problem, I needed a dot at the end of the domain and at the end of the name server. The configuration for BIND was handled by Virtualmin automatically and setup each zone as `${DOM} IN NS ns1.thirteen.pm`. I adjusted this to read `${DOM}. IN NS ns1.thirteen.pm.` and this fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks Hakan, silly me, didn't even look at that part